# How to switch templates in C++11 at runtime?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variant

I created a Socket Wrapper. It can be instantiated with two templates:

```
Socket<asio::ip::udp>
Socket<asio::ip::tcp>
```

In a Singleton class I want to instantiate one of the two, but I get a runtime parameter which makes the choice. How do I instantiate one of the tow at runtime?

I'm aware of `boost::variant`, is there a way without?

Comment: You can't do it in a nice way. One possibility is to have an abstract base class which `Socket<protocol>` inherits from. Then you can have a factory function which returns a pointer to the base class, and which creates the correct instance.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that base class would have to have virtual methods, making templates a bit pointless. Right?

Comment: @freakish Not really pointless. It would remove their "no need for virtual calls" speed advantage, which only matters if the code is time-critical enough. The advantage of "write the code only once to work with different types" would remain.

Comment: @freakish Maybe. But as I also said, there's no nice way to do it.

Comment: Beware, C++ uses templates and not generics. That means that instantiation does occur at build time, not at run time: one different class have to be compiled for each instantiation in the program. That also means that templating is not the direct tool to use for your question. In OO programming, the natural design would be a common base class as suggested by Someprogrammerdude. `std:variant` or any other way based on `void *` may help too. The best way depends on tons of parameters, including what you have already used, and know better.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude a abstract base class did the trick. Thanks!